# What is the rank of a linear map $T$ on the space of $n\times n$ matrices such that $T(A)=0$ for any symmetric or skew-symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be the vector space of all $n\times n$ matrices and $T:M\to M$ be a linear transformation such that $T(A) = 0$, where $A$ denotes all symmetric and skew symmetric matrices. Then what is the rank of $T$? $\mathrm{rank}(T) = \dim(M)-\mathrm{nullity}(T)$. Dimension of $M$ is $n^2$ but what is its nullity?

Comment: Can you think of any example of what transformation $T$ could be?

Comment: My previous question may be obsolete, but I will note: The idea that $T$ could be simply the $0$ map could come without knowing much.  Even if there could be other maps that satisfy the given condition, the $0$ map is certainly an option.  Hence if the question has a unique answer, you have it there.  However, that in itself doesn't tell you why there is a unique answer, and for that Zev's approach is good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Considering the case of $n=2$, observe that any $2\times 2$ matrix can be written as
$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a & \tfrac{b+c}{2} \\ \tfrac{b+c}{2} & d\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0 & \tfrac{b-c}{2} \\ \tfrac{c-b}{2}  & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
Can you generalize this observation? What does this imply about how $T$ acts on any matrix?

Comment: is rank 0? since dimension is 4 and nullity is also 4

Comment: To make my point clearer: can you see what kinds of matrices the two on the right side of the equation are?

Comment: yes. 1st is symmetric and 2nd is skew symmetric.

Comment: every matrix can be written as a sum of symmetric and a skew symmetric matrices, so T maps every matrix to 0. is it correct?

Comment: Yup, that's right!